# NUnit CPU usage very high - How to resolve?

Tags: nunit

On numerous unrelated, projects the CPU usage of NUnit has often ended up being about 50% even when I'm not running my tests. From other information I've read this is supposedly more to do with my code than Nunit.

Does anyone know how I can isolate the problems in my code that will be causing this and fix them?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and it seems to be rather consistently affecting only one test project doing integration testing (calling web services, checking stuff over HTTP, etc). I'm very careful to dispose of networked objects (with `using(...){ }`), so I don't quite understand why NUnit should continue to use 90% CPU days after the test is done with and all objects in use by the test should be disposed of.

The really strange thing is that while running the test, NUnit uses no more than 10%-50% CPU. It's only after the test has completed that CPU usage surges and stays constantly at 80%-100% forever. It's really strange. Reloading or closing the test project (File > Close) doesn't help either. NUnit itself needs to be closed.